# Query in order of filters from query - solr

Tags: solr

Folks,

We wanted to make sure that solr queries the data based on the filter order.

E.g If input is given like "Please help someone here" then first it should query data based on below ( All below are in 5 different documents for us)

"Please help"
"help someone"
"someone here"

Then by

"please"
"help"
 etc

We saw solr is picking the index randomly and the searching document

e.g. if we search for "please help someone here" it is making hit in to document which is having text like "help required" ( This is coming in the middle but should be at bottom)

```
<analyzer type="query">
         <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/> 

        <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" minShingleSize="2" maxShingleSize="4" outputUnigrams="false"/> 
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    </analyzer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Index into two different fields, one for Shingle matches (as you've defined) and one for the free text match. Score matches differently by using `qf=shinglefield^10 textfield` - so that a match in shinglefield will be scored ten times higher than a match in the regular text field. You'll need to tweak these weights depending on your own need.

`qf` is a valid parameter if using edismax or the old dismax query parser.

Comment: How can we index only shingles on a field (not indivisual tokens). It seems it is mandatory to provide tokenizer before provide Shingle filter. We tried adding ( KeywordTokenizerFactory,WhiteSpaceTokenizerFactory,StandardTokenizerFactory)

Comment: The ShingleFilterFactory with unigrams set to false and minGrams 2 should not output any tokens that are just single values as far as I know. Use the analysis page to confirm that the setup is correct.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your help We are facing one more problem we want to order our response such that the result will appear in following order 1)"google facebook" 2) "google" 3) "facebook" but it seems we are getting facebook before google.(with shinglefilerfactory we are getting 'google facebook'  as first document thanks for that). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35532824/solr-nested-boosting-not-working-as-expected